# cookie value empty in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of my programs I set a cookie which contains the `allowed_apps` for the user. In Google chrome when user logs in it shows the allowed apps for the user without any problem. But it does not work on IE. When I debugged it on IE, It says that the `cookie('allowed_apps')` is empty. The strange thing is when I checked in Chrome `cookie('allowed_apps')` was empty too. But anyhow the apps are working in chrome. I cleared all browsing history in both browsers and tried, but still the same. Both show that `cookie('allowed_apps')` is empty. But only chrome works like there is some value in `cookie('allowed_apps')`. By the way I Am using `jquery.cookie.js` to manage cookies.

In user_manager.js

```
var perm_list = '';
var allowed_apps = [];

for (i=0; i<response_data[0].permissions.length; i++) {
    perm_list += response_data[0].permissions[i].permissions;
    if ("" != response_data[0].permissions[i].permissions) {
        allowed_apps.push(obj_common.str_replace("_permissions", "", response_data[0].permissions[i].app_name));
    }
}

$.cookie('allowed_apps', allowed_apps);
```

And in `home.js` I get the cookie

```
    var allowed_apps = $.cookie('allowed_apps').split(",");
```

Comment: How about you show a code snippet of how you're using `$.cookie`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently writing the array, `allowed_apps`, to a cookie; cookies can only be a string. Encode the array before you write.

Two ways to do this:

- [`$.cookie.json = true;`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#json) //jQuery.cookie will automatically handle encoding and decoding values for you in json
- When writings use: `$.cookie('allowed_apps', JSON.stringify(allowed_apps));`
  Reading: `var allowed_apps = JSON.parse($.cookie('allowed_apps'));`

If you set `cookie.json` change the getter to just

```
var allowed_apps = $.cookie('allowed_apps');
```

Comment: Cookies have a size limit.  Don't know how large that array can be, but size could be an issue.

Comment: if your site is html5 you can use `localStorage` which has 5 mb limit by default

Comment: Thanks megawac..It worked for me. I added JSON.stringify(allowed_apps)...and now all ok. Thanks.